# How to delete subsite without any permissions?

Tags: 2010, permissions

I have a subsite, I broke permissions that are inherited from parent to create unique permissions, then I accidentally deleted all of the permissions for this subsite. Now I'm just like a simple user without any modification rights, I can see the subsite, walk in it, but I can't manage or modify or delete it.

How can I delete the subsite, without required permissions?

Comment: Before I try and answer, can you advise if you have any administration tools, such as ControlPoint that might help with this? What version of SharePoint you are using.?

Comment: @karthik, I haven't any controlpoint. The version is SP2010

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the server you could delete it using powershell script : [link to source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607890.aspx)

```
Remove-SPWeb [-Identity] <SPWebPipeBind> [-AssignmentCollection <SPAssignmentCollection>] [-Confirm [<SwitchParameter>]] [-Recycle <SwitchParameter>] [-WhatIf [<SwitchParameter>]]
```

Comment: but why would you want to delete the subsite? maybe he has alot of info on the site and wants to regain control? ;)

Comment: Because his question was: "How can I delete the subsite, without required permissions?")

Comment: lol you right ;) totally missed that! man its been a long week ;)

Comment: @user2954017 do you have access to the server?

Comment: @andrey, it doesn't work for me. Error: Remove-SPWeb : Cannot access the local farm. Verify that the local farm is properly configured, currently available, and that you have the appropriate permissions to access the database before trying again.

Comment: @ali, no I haven't...

Comment: you need to do it on the server meaning you need to be farm admin! or have some admin privlages on the server

Comment: @ali, I'm already in Farm Administrators group, that is the point.

Comment: Did you run SharePoint Management Shell "as administrator"?

Answer (score 2):

if your site collection admin than its simple!

goto `http://YouRootUrl/YourSubsiteName/_layouts/user.aspx` and now select Inherit Permissions within the ribbon, that should reset the site back to normal!

or goto:

central admin -> under site collection click on 'change site collection admin' -> within the drop down box for site collection you can select the site, on the right side it will show you the site on the left the subsite, select the subsite in question and click ok. now add your user account name and click ok! you should be able to login to the subsite as normal!

lol just noticed the deletion part ;) atleast the above is to give you control to the subsite again without having to delete the subsite :)

you could use stsadm aswell!

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262877(v=office.12).aspx

```
stsadm -o deleteweb -url http://server_name/sites/site_name/subsite_name -force
```

i know stsadm is for 2007 but it works in 2010 ;)

Comment: ok dont use force!

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261873(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: that error means you dont have access to the server! have you run stsadm as admin and not just opend it up? right click cmd and run as admin!

Comment: @user2954017 have you tried the other methods first? get the site working and than delete it would be simpler!

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: @user2954017 do you have access to central admin on the server?